# How to evaluate $\int_0^1 \frac{\log x}{x-1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$I = \int_0^1 \frac{\log x}{x-1}dx$$
I tried to let $\log x = t \implies dx = e^t dt$
$$I = \int_0^1 \frac{te^t}{e^t-1}dt = \frac12+\int_0^1 \frac{t}{e^t-1}dt$$
I could not go further than this step, other than prove that $I > \frac12$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I = \int_0^1\frac{\log x}{x-1} dx= -\int_0^1\log x(1+x+x^2+...)dx \\ 
= -\int_0^1 \log x \sum_{r=0}^\infty x^r dx \\
= -\sum_{r=0}^\infty\int_0^1x^r \log x dx$$
let $\log x = t \implies dx = e^t dt$:
$$I = -\sum_{r=0}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^0te^{(r+1)t}dt\\
=-\sum_{r=0}^\infty \left[\frac{te^{(r+1)t}}{(r+1)} - \frac{e^{(r+1)t}}{(r+1)^2}\right]_{-\infty}^0 \\
= \sum_{r=0}^\infty \left[\frac{1}{(r+1)^2} + \lim_{t \to -\infty} \frac{(t(r+1)-1)e^{(r+1)t}}{(r+1)^2} \right]\\
= \sum_{r=0}^\infty \left[\frac{1}{(r+1)^2} - \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{(t(r+1)+1)}{e^{(r+1)t}(r+1)^2} \right] \\
= \sum_{r=0}^\infty \left[\frac{1}{(r+1)^2} - \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{r+1}{e^{(r+1)t}(r+1)^3} \right] \\
= \sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(r+1)^2}\\
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}\\
= \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

The computation of the series $\sum \frac 1 {k^2}$ is also known as the [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) and has many good proofs [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2-basel-pro) and [here](http://math.cmu.edu/~bwsulliv/basel-problem.pdf)

The general form of this integral is known as [Spence's Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function) or Dilogarithm. It's a transcendental function which has the values $Li_2(0)=0$ and $Li_2(1)=\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. If you know these values beforehand, you can cut out the lengthy calculation.

**EDIT:** Another easy way to calculate the integral is by using the taylor series expansion of $\log(1-x)$
$$I = -\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-x)}{x}dx = \int_0^1 1 + \frac x2 + \frac{x^2}{3}+ \frac{x^3}{4} + ... dx\\ 
= \left[x + \frac{x^2}{2^2} + \frac{x^3}{3^2} + ... \right]_0^1 \\
= 1 + \frac1 {2^2} + \frac1 {3^2} + \frac 1 {4^2} + ...\\
= \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$